# Factory Design Pattern and Diamond OOP issue

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

In one of my projects, I have to implement the Factory design pattern to solve a specific issue.

I have one parent interface and two child interfaces. In the next stage, I have to create a factory which will return an instance of a specific class based on given input.

Please see my sample code below which explains my problem and the sample diagram as well.

## Sample Diagram

[image]

## Sample Code

```
enum AnimalType{ DOG, CAT }

Class Factory{
    public Animal getInstance(AnimalType animalType){
        Animal animal = null;
        switch(animalType){
            case DOG: animal = new Dog();
                break;

            case CAT: animal = new Cat();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return animal;
    }
}

/*Actual Problem */
Animal animal = Factory.getInstance(AnimalType.DOG);

  /* When I use any IDE like IntellijIdea or Eclipse it only provides eat() method after animal and dot (ie. animal. ) */
animal.<SHOULD PROVIDE eat() and woof() from Dog> but it is only providing eat()
```

Any advice to overcome this problem? Or, should I consider any other Design Pattern for this problem?

Comment: It's declared as an Animal, not a Dog. Declare `animal` as a `Dog`, then try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not directly related to the factory pattern. You are declaring an `Animal` and then want to treat it as a `Dog`. It doesn't matter how you create it you will need to make it a `Dog` to call doggy methods.

You have many options to resolve this. Here are a few alternatives.

1. Have separate methods for creating different extensions of `Animal`. So instead of `Animal getInstance(AnimalType type)` you would have `Dog getDog()` and `Cat getCat()` methods in the factory. Given the factory needs to be aware of all these classes anyway this seems like the best option to me.
2. Continue to return `Animal` instances from your factory but then use the 'visitor' pattern to treat dogs and cats differently.
3. Use `instanceof` and casting to treat animals as dogs or cats. This is not recommended for most situations but is suitable in some cases.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is related to **`"General OO"`** not really about **`Factory`** design pattern. Now let's take a look at your three interfaces: **`Animal`**, **`Dog`** and **`Cat`**. The **`Dog`** and **`Cat`** are implemented the **`Animal`** interface, it does not mean that they have exactly the same behaviors with difference implementations, what we can make sure is they will respect the behaviors of **`Animal`**.

**For instance:**

1. The **`Dog`** and **`Cat`** will have the same behavior is **`eat()`**
2. The **`Dog`** has a **`woof()`** behavior which do not exist in the **`Cat`**
3. The **`Cat`** has a **`miaw()`** behavior which do not exist in the **`Dog`**

Therefore, when you implement the **Simple Factory** (according to Head Of Design Pattern it is not real design pattern, just a programming idiom) to deal with create object and return the **`Animal`** interface, it means you are considering the **`Dog`** and **`Cat`** as an **`Animal`** with the same behavior is **`eat()`**. That's why you can not do somethings like this in your code

```
/*Actual Problem */
Animal animal = Factory.getInstance(AnimalType.DOG);

  /* When I use any IDE like IntellijIdea or Eclipse it only provides eat() method after animal and dot (ie. animal. ) */
animal.<SHOULD PROVIDE eat() and woof() from Dog> but it is only providing eat()
```

**In my opinion, there are some possible implementations**:

1. For simplicity, you can create 2 **Simple Factory**, one for **`Dog`** and other is **`Cat`**
2. If you know what you want, you can cast the **`Animal`** to **`Dog`** or **`Cat`**, and then use their functions
3. Implement the Abstract Factory pattern, it will provide and abstract interface for creating a family of product (**`Dog`** and **`Cat`**).

I hope it can help you.